# detecte a rising edge with RA4 with pic18f4550

Tags: c, counter, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am using a pic 18f4550 , is there a method to detect the passage of the rising edge on RA4.
I can't use ccp1 or ccp2 because they are already busy.

Comment: Maybe INT1 interrupt?

Comment: can you explain to me how it works, if you want.

Comment: INT1 is on GPIO pin RB1 so this will not do what you want on RA4. It is possible to detect an edge transition on the RA4 input and assert an interrupt event by using TIMER0 in asynchronous counter mode with the TIMER0 external clock on RA4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did a bit of research and figured out how it works. I will try to use it to achieve what I want.